# remote shutdown with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, server

I have a simple script to shutdown all our servers remotely if you have the right credentials like

> -Credential domain/administrator

Is it possible to change this to en entire user group or orgisation unit instead of a single user since we have multiple admins here?

Comment: No, you can't specify more than one set of credentials.

Comment: I suppose you could loop until you are done the credential set or ran out of credentials.

Comment: How do you know which admin is associated with a specific server?

Answer (score 0):

Why would there not be a set of credentials that could be sued across the board, or at least for groups of servers?  Failing that maybe there SHOULD be an account across the board that could do this such as a provilaged service account or similar.